# Why do some model objects reset every time i redeploy and after a while of time passes in Django Heroku?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku, django-storage

This is probably a really dumb question.

Every time I redeploy my django app on heroku i get the same two instances of my object that were there before i deployed. I would like to change these. I would like to add some. I would like to delete some. But every time I redeploy, and after some time passes after I make changes, it always reverts back to what it was. It is horrible. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

NOTE: I AM ALREADY HOLDING MY FILES SOMEWHERE ELSE. I don't believe this has anything to do with the ephemeral file system, since I already am storing files somewhere else. But why is it that every time I redeploy the instances of the objects themselves (instances of the things inside Models) go away??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to instances in your database? Can you provide more information about what DB you are using and how it is deployed?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I think I'm just using the default database.

Comment: Sounds like you are using SQLite ist it?

Comment: Sure, I think so. I see 'sqlite' in my settings

Comment: By "default database" do you mean an sqlite database file that has been committed to your repository?

Comment: Ah, I found the file you're referring to. Yes, that must be what I am doing @IainShelvington

Comment: @bernardo you should look into using a database that is deployed separately to your application. What's happening is every tie your app is deployed the sqlite file is overwritten with the one that is in the repo, effectively "resetting" your database

Comment: Perfect, do you know of any good places to start? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have a look at [Configuring Django Apps for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

Comment: Docs on how to deploy postgres on heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql